# Orbitally convenient Mars-to-Earth transit times?

Tags: orbit, earth, mars, space-travel

Are there any peculiar solar system layouts that would result in highly efficient transits between Mars-to-Earth? I am aware of a Hohmann transfer orbit, but can other planets be used to "sling-shot" large quantities of cargo from Mars to Earth in an efficient manner?

If these cannot be answered directly, what would be the best way to go about calculating interesting orbital positions within the next 1000 years?

Comment: I think there's some interesting things you can do with Venus to help with Earth/Mars trips.  These links may be of interest: https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/2.3778?journalCode=jsr ; https://engineering.purdue.edu/AAC/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/FastMarsFreeReturnsviaVenusGravityAssist-AIAA-2014-4109.pdf ; https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19660006110.pdf

Comment: This belongs on a different WWW site, alongside the likes of https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6359/16044 and https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14589/16044 .